# How can I fix this error while uploading csv to bigquery?

Tags: python, csv, google-bigquery

I am getting the below error while uploading a CSV to bigquery using Python:

google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse '80:00:00' as TIME for field global_time_for_first_response_goal (position 36) starting at location 11602908  with message 'Invalid time string "80:00:00"' File: gs://mybucket/mytickets/2023-02-1309:58:11:865588.csv

```
def upload_csv_bigquery_dataset():
    # logging.info(">>> Uploading CSV to Big Query")
    client      = bigquery.Client()
    table_id    = "myproject-dev.tickets.ticket"
    job_config  = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        write_disposition     = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
        source_format         = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
        schema                = [bigquery.table_schema],
        skip_leading_rows     = 1,
        autodetect            = True,
        allow_quoted_newlines = True
    )
    uri = "gs://mybucket/mytickets/2023-02-1309:58:11:865588.csv"
    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
    )  # Make an API request.

    load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

    destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)
    print(">>> Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

Can someone please tell me a fix or a workaround please? Stuck at this.

Comment: What is the time "80:00:00" supposed to represent?

Comment: It's supposed to be an SLA time stamp field on the Jira ticket.

Comment: That's clearly not a timestamp.  Is it supposed to be an elapsed time in hours?

Comment: oh yes, that's elapsed time for first response. So yes total time.

Comment: Then it's inaccurate to call it a TIME.  Perhaps you should convert that field to integer minutes or floating point hours, or something like that.

Comment: Is there a way for me to skip or replace these error fields with null while uploading them to big query from the csv? Updating the code that generates the csv is not in my scope.

Comment: Well actually it's exactly opposite of what we discussed, it's actually a TIME stamp field, it says "time for first response". As you said 80:00:00 is not a valid time stamp, it's giving an error. Can I skip these values and replace them with null while uploading to bigquery?

Comment: I think you would have to modify the CSV.

Comment: Can you share with us an example of CSV line and also the `BigQuery` table schema please ?

Comment: Added a workaround that helped.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution/Workaround:**

The following fixed it for me.

So my entire CSV file of 10000 lines had just one row with an erroneous field. It was difficult to reproduce this or fix this in the code that was generating the CSV. So I did this:

```
def upload_csv_bigquery_dataset(uniqueDateTime):
    logging.info(">>> Uploading CSV to Big Query")
    client      = bigquery.Client()
    table_id    = "my-project-dev.tickets.ticket"
    MAX_BAD_RECORDS = 1
    job_config  = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        write_disposition     = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
        source_format         = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
        skip_leading_rows     = 1,
        max_bad_records       = MAX_BAD_RECORDS, #Skip one or more bad records 
        autodetect            = True,
        allow_quoted_newlines = True
    )
    uri = "gs://myticket/my/" + uniqueDateTime
    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
    )  # Make an API request.

    load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

    destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)
    print(">>> Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

Basically used the max_bad_records option in my job_config to ignore that error record and write all my data to big query.